# Job listing sticky container

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If you look closely when scrolling down any job listing page for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/111924/magento-front-end-developer-inverse-paradox-llc) the bar `.detail-header-block` which contains the name and company changes from a static to a fixed box when scrolling down.

The problem is the content starting under Job Description does not adapt itself when the bar changes making it shoot up once you scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the report, @Joost! This should be fixed now.